# Null coalescing operator also usable with falsy values, but not nulls?

Tags: null-coalescing-operator, php-7

The new **null coalescing operator** in PHP is surely a great feature, somewhat comparable to JavaScript's usage of `||` for getting default values.

I already read some documentations and articles about this feature, but some things are still not quite clear to me.

**1.** Can I use this operator with any number of operands? For example, would this be valid?

`$a = $p1 ?? $p2;`

`$b = $r1 ?? $r2 ?? $r3 ?? $r4 ?? $r5;`

**2.** What is about falsy values, which are not null?

`$test = false ?? 0 ?? 'test';` - what will be `$test` now? If it doesn't work with falsy values other than null, how can we achieve, that it works like JavaScript's `||`?

Comment: If you want something close to JavaScript's `||`, use the shorthand ternary operator, `?:`. That doesn't do `isset()` for you, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created [this](http://3v4l.org/eRM6C) which should answer you questions.

Anyhow

1. The operator can be chained and it will return the first element in the chain that is set and not null.
2. According to the [documentation](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/isset_ternary) it will `return the result of its first operand if it exists and is not NULL, or else its second operand`. Hence, if the first operand is `false`, it will return `false`.